# Sign in with google - Authentication

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing an android app where in the user has the option to both Sign in by registering to the app and also use the Sign in with google option.

Sign in with form is working perfectly fine. But when the user signs in with google, I redirect the user to the Sign up screen to get more information before I log the user into the Main Screen. My only problem is, when the user Signs in with google for the first time, the user is redirected to the second screen where he registers his/her additional information.

My requirement is that, only when the user Signs in with google for the first time, I want him to be redirected to the SIgn up activity to get more information. After first time, I want him to be redirected directly to the main screen. How do I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far. Just posting the code that is necessary.

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this,ContactDetailsActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };
else if(view == signInWithGoogleButton)
    {
        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Signing in with google...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
            Toast.makeText(this,"not signed in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    //updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

In the sign up screen, I just get information regarding the user's phone number, date of birth and so. So my question is, the first time the user clicks on the Sign in with google button, the user has to go through the sign up. After the first time, I want him redirected directly to Main screen.

Please help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think enableAutoManage can solve this problem

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```